# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite 2.0 to HTML Page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have the following rule:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="FlowURLs">
                <match url="^flows/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/([._0-9a-zA-Z-]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="music.html?flow={R:1}" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(ashx|axd|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|flv|f4v|html)$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

What I am trying to do is if a url is incoming something like the following:

```
http://localhost/flows/t/twit_nobone/twit_nobone1354334226132.mp3
```

I want to rewrite it to:

```
http://localhost/music.html?id=twit_nobone1354334226132.mp3
```

The music.html resides in the root and it has a stylesheet, javascript and images.  The problem I am seeing is that when it rewrites, no images, js or stylesheets are being displayed.  When I inspect the resources, it looks like the links are now

```
http://localhost/flows/t/twit_nobone/twit_nobone1354334226132.mp3/demo.css
http://localhost/flows/t/twit_nobone/twit_nobone1354334226132.mp3/images/screenshot.png
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/demo.css
http://localhost/images/screenshot.png
```

What am I doing wrong?  I also noticed that the url in the browser never changes to the rewritten one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to possibilities how to solve this issue.

1: if you want to keep address like `http://localhost/flows/t/twit_nobone/twit_nobone1354334226132.mp3`
then make sure that any resources in `music.html` are linked absolutely so instead of `test.css` make it `/path/to/test.css` from root server. Then it will work.

2: if you prefer address like
`http://localhost/music.html?id=twit_nobone1354334226132.mp3`
**EDIT**

I just found out it is simple - change the action to:

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="music.html?flow={R:1}" />
```